# Details for pre exposure prophylaxis for rabies

Tags: vaccination, rabies, preventative-medicine

I will now be in contact with many unvaccinated dogs. I will have to take the pre exposure course. Please tell me how frequently it is taken. Will I require boosters if a dog bites me after I have taken the pre exposure course? Please tell me everything I should know. I could not find much in the internet and I will not be able to go to a doctor for some days. Thank You.